# Howto disable unit test runs, when building custom Python packages

Tags: linux, functional-programming, nix, guix

**TLDR**

When building a custom (Github hosted) Python package, how can we disable unit test runs?

**DETAIL**

I'm trying to make a custom guix package from [maurosoria/dirsearch](https://github.com/maurosoria/dirsearch).

This is [the configuration](https://github.com/twashing/dotfiles/blob/main/guix/packages/dirsearch.scm#L34) that I have.

But building it gives this error (see https://snippet.host/fzavuc).

```
guix build -L ~/dotfiles/ python-dirsearch
...
FAILED tests/_ntlm_raw/test_crypto.py::test_ntowfv2 - ValueError: unsupported...
FAILED tests/_ntlm_raw/test_crypto.py::test_compute_response_v2 - ValueError:...
================== 44 failed, 392 passed, 80 skipped in 4.71s ==================
error: in phase 'check': uncaught exception:
%exception #<&invoke-error program: "pytest" arguments: () exit-status: 1 term-signal: #f stop-signal: #f>
phase `check' failed after 5.2 seconds
command "pytest" failed with status 1
```

Basically it's trying to run the project's unit tests, even though I tried to disable that with [this config](https://github.com/twashing/dotfiles/blob/main/guix/packages/dirsearch.scm#L46).

How do I disable that unit test run?